# How can I achieve complete Code Coverage for OR Statements in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-2017

I was just wondering about how the code coverage works in visual studio. Here is a very simple version of my scenario.

```
if (A || B)
{
    //Do the thing
}
```

I have 4 unit tests to assert whether the "thing" is done or not, testing against all possible permutations of A and B like so:

- **A' + B'** Assert thing was **not** done
- **A' + B** Assert thing was done
- **A + B'** Assert thing was done
- **A + B** Assert thing was done

All of these tests predictably pass. The problem is that I am still getting a "partially" covered result for the if condition itself. As far as I know, I have every possibility covered. Is there something I am missing here?

Thank you in advance, feel free to redirect me if there is an answer for this already, but I could not find one. In fact, the answers I did find said that I should have 100% coverage, so I wanted to see what you guys think.

**Something to Note:**
I am not sure if this makes any difference, but technically A and B are comparisons of properties of 2 instances of the same class, so really the code looks like this:

```
if(oldObj.ValueA != newObj.ValueA || oldObj.ValueB != newObj.ValueB)
{
    //do the thing
}
```

Hope that is enough detail, thanks again. I realize that obsessing over 100% coverage is silly, but this is mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: Are you testing coverage in debug mode or in release mode?

Comment: The company I am working for have removed debug/release and replaced with their own configurations, basically Dev, QA, Prod, etc. so I don't know how to answer that accurately.

Comment: essentially the question is: with optimizations, or without optimizations?  With what level of optimizations?

Comment: Which one of these are you using then? If it is not Prod, could you try using Prod?

Comment: I tried in both Dev and Prod and got the same result. I am not sure how to answer the questions about optimizations. I still lack experience in terms of build/deploy stuff. I will try creating a brand new project and see if that makes a difference

Comment: What do you use to run the tests and to check the coverage? Resharper, NUnit, XUnit, MSTest or something different?

Comment: Turns out my sample project does not show this behavior. I am assuming it must have something to do with the company's custom configurations

Comment: @Iqon I am using the baked in unit test project. I assume it would be MSTest, but the package is at "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting"

Comment: To reach fully coverage you should only need one tests: A' + B will cover both branches in the "or", and the if statements body. My local test project confirms this.

Comment: @Iqon my local test project got 100% as well, but I had all 4 permutations, I guess this must be some kind of other weird issue that the others have mentioned. I would be curious to see if that could be recreated (and if it is worth fixing)